# 'object' does not contain a definition for 'rxDetail'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

***Controller code***

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var data = (from pd in db.Prescription_Details join md in db.Medicine_Details 
                        on pd.Medicine_Id equals md.Medicine_Id 
                        select new MyPrescription {rxDetail=pd.Rx_Detail_Id , medicineName=md.Medicine_Name , dosageFrequency= pd.Dosage_Frequency}).ToList();  

            var prescs = db.Prescription_Details.Select(x => x.Prescription.Doctor_Details.Doctor_Name).Distinct().ToList();
            //entity
            ViewBag.prescriptions = prescs;
            ViewBag.dd = data;
            return View();
        }

Razor code 
 @foreach (var item in ViewBag.dd)
                                        {
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>@item.rxDetail</td>
                                                <td>@item.medicineName</td>
                                                <td>@item.dosageFrequency</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        }
```

Apart from making new class MyPrescriptions I am getting this error . Is there some other way to proceed with it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ViewBag` internally stores defined properties value as Object. It is actually a dynamic type defined by [ExpandoObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx) that stored the data as dictionary. Once you convert any `custom object` to type `object` then it won't know underlying properties of custom object unless you explicitly cast it.

So all you need to do is cast it to your custom object before using:

<del>@foreach (var item in ViewBag.dd as MyPrescription)</del>

```
@foreach (MyPrescription item in ViewBag.dd)
```

Comment: If it solved your problem then you can accept it as answer. it will help other users seeking similar problems.

Comment: Actually , I just made My Prescription class as Public and It worked . I did not use the 'as' keyword.

Comment: This won't even compile... 
It casts `ViewBag.dd` to `MyPrescription` before trying to enumerate it.
To cast each element of `ViewBag.dd` you should use `@foreach (MyPrescription item in ViewBag.dd)`, which also won't compile unless `MyPrescription` is public.

Comment: @Jakub Good catch!! This is too naive mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Is your `MyPrescription` class internal? Razor views are compiled into a separate assembly, so internal classes are not accessible there.

Trying to access properties of an inaccessible class from a `dynamic` variable throws the exception you get.

Comment: No MyPrescription class is not internal

Comment: @Anish In the comment to the other answer you just said that making the class public helped. That's exactly what I suggested here.

Comment: Oh , yeah !! I inferred something else , Thanks Man !